# Why switch won't execute while condition

Tags: c++, switch-statement, do-while

Can somebody please explain to me why this code won't execute the while condition?
I just want to know why the code behaves this way or if there are other ways to make it work.Thanks

UPDATE!!!

Hi by the way this is the code, I am not very familiar with C++ so I am not sure while the program skips the while condition on switch. Thanks

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstring>
#include<vector>
#define MAX 100
using namespace std;
int main()
{
void remove(char[]);
void add(char[], char);
char cstring[MAX];
char letter;
int ecount;
std::string str;
char selection;

cout << "Enter String: ";
cin.getline(cstring, MAX);
cout << "Size of String: " << strlen(cstring) << endl;

bool gameOn = true;
while (gameOn != false){
cout<<"\n Menu";
cout<<"\n========";
cout<<"\n A - Append";
cout<<"\n X - Exit";
cout<<"\n Enter selection: ";
cin>>selection;

switch(selection)
{
case 'A' :
case 'a' :
    cout << " Add Element: ";
    while (letter!='\n')
    {
    letter = cin.get();
    add(cstring, letter);
    }

    cout << "\n Output String: " << cstring;
    ecount = strlen(cstring) - 1;
    cout << " Size of String: " << ecount<< endl;
    break;
case 'X' :
case 'x' :{cout<<"\n To exit the menu";}
    break;
    default : cout<<"\n !!Invalid selection!!"<< endl;
    }
}
cout<<"\n";
return 0;
}


char * add( char *cstring, char c )
{
   int letter = strlen( cstring );

   if ( letter < MAX - 1 )
   {
      cstring[letter] = c;
      cstring[letter + 1] = '\0';
   }

   return ( cstring );
}
```

Comment: What's in `letter` before the `switch`?

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess here, but it's probably because `letter == '\n'`

Comment: The `switch` probably has nothing to do with the `while` not executing. Verify that the actual conditions match i.e. `selection` equals 'A' or 'a' and `letter` does not equal '\n'.

Comment: Put you'r complete code.

Comment: Are you saying that your compiler gave you an **error message**?  And you don't want us to see that message?

Comment: Yes. The code you have provided executes properly. The developer who wrote it however does not. Use a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Its my wild guess.
I think you have to initialize `letter`.

check it out by using the following code.
And yes debug for the value of `selection` you are passing to switch too.

```
switch(selection)
{
case 'A' :
case 'a' :
    cout << "Add Element: ";

    letter = cin.get(); // this will initialize the char letter;

    while (letter != '\n') // or use ascii value of new line char in while condition 
    {
      add(cstring, letter); // first add it to string
      letter = cin.get(); // then get next letter  
    }

   cout << "String: " << cstring;
   ecount = strlen(cstring) - 1; // ecount must be a int
   cout << "Size of String: " << ecount<< endl;
break;
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: why you need to initialize letter it will not contain '\n' and while loop has to execute the code is correct the problem is in 'selection' he is not passing the correct case thats it?

Comment: @thehand02 have you tried by debugging the code? if Yes, What is the value in `selection` variable.. if no, please do it and check it once

Comment: @thehand02 I have checked this application it is working fine as you want it to be. Just try once again that replace the condition of `while` for checking with ascii value of `\n`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the input you are reading, When you read a character in the

```
cin>>selection;
```

It will read a char and put it into selection and when you press enter it will be get stored in the `letter` and you'r while loop will never execute.

see the code below it is working fine;

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstring>
#include<vector>
#define MAX 100
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    void remove(char[]);
    void add(char[], char);
    char cstring[MAX];
    char letter;
    int ecount;
    std::string str;
    char selection;

    cout << "Enter String: ";
    cin.getline(cstring, MAX);
    cout << "Size of String: " << strlen(cstring) << endl;

    bool gameOn = true;
    while (gameOn != false){
        cout<<"\n Menu";
        cout<<"\n========";
        cout<<"\n A - Append";
        cout<<"\n X - Exit";
       cout<<"\n Enter selection: ";


       cin>>selection;
       cout<<"\n selection="<<selection;

       switch(selection)
       {
        case 'A' :
        case 'a' :
              selection=cin.get();
              cout << " Add Element: ";
              while (letter!='\n')
               {
                letter = cin.get();

                 add(cstring, letter);
               } 

               cout << "\n Output String: " << cstring;
               ecount = strlen(cstring) - 1;
               cout << " Size of String: " << ecount<< endl;
         break;
      case 'X' :
      case 'x' :cout<<"\n To exit the menu";
                gameOn=false;
      break;
      default : cout<<"\n !!Invalid selection!!"<< endl;
      } 
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Is the `cout<<Selection` will make any difference in the program execution?

Comment: I put that cout<<selection just for showing that he is reading the input correctly. You'r guess was correct but we don't need to initialize letter.